# Single.defer() not executed

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have an issue wherein my Single.defer block is not being executed.

documentRepository.getDocuments() is called to get documents from DB:

```
class GetReports
@Inject constructor(
        private val reportRepository: ReportRepository,
        private val documentRepository: DocumentRepository,
        threadExecutor: ThreadExecutor,
        postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread
) : SingleUseCase<List<Report>, Void?>(
        threadExecutor, postExecutionThread) {

    override fun buildUseCaseObservable(params: Void?): Single<List<Report>> {
        return reportRepository
                .getReports()
                .flatMap { reports ->
                    val finalReports = ArrayList<Report>()

                    reports.forEach { report ->
                        documentRepository.getDocuments(report.id!!)
                                .map { documents ->
                                    finalReports.add(Report(report.id, report.name, report.status,
                                            report.dateCreated, documents))
                                }
                    }

                    Single.just(finalReports.toList())
                }
    }

}
```

The first Timber.d() logging code gets executed so I know it enters this method but the whole Single.defer code after that is not executed -- debug is not entering inside the block and the second Timber.d() logging code is also not executed.

```
override fun getDocuments(reportId: Long): Single<List<Document>> {
        Timber.d("Getting documents for report ID $reportId")

        return Single.defer<List<Document>> {
            try {
                Timber.d("Getting document cursor for report ID $reportId")
                val documentCursor = database.query(
                        Db.DocumentTable.TABLE_NAME,
                        null,
                        Db.DocumentTable.REPORT_ID + "= $reportId",
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                )
                Timber.d("Got document cursor for report ID $reportId. Row count: ${documentCursor.count}")
                getDocuments(documentCursor)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e, "Error getting documents for report ID $reportId")
                Single.error(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing it incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @azizbekian said, there was nothing that subscribed to the `getDocuments`. However, calling `subscribe()` inside that `flatMap` is discouraged as it breaks the flow. Instead, you should create an inner flow and return that in the `flatMap` of reports:

```
override fun buildUseCaseObservable(params: Void?): Single<List<Report>> {
    return reportRepository
            .getReports()
            .flatMap { reports ->
                Observable.fromIterable(reports)
                .concatMap { report ->
                    documentRepository.getDocuments(report.id!!) 
                    .map { documents ->
                         Report(report.id, report.name, report.status,
                                 report.dateCreated, documents))
                    }.toObservable()
                }
                .toList()
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried using that, but 1) I'm getting a type mismatch error (Required: (Report) ObservableSource... Found: (Report) Single<Report>) and 2) the `.toList()` call is not available for the concatMap()

Comment: Updated, try now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you are essentialy doing:

```
    documentRepository.getDocuments(...)
                      .map { ...}
```

Nobody is subscribing to this stream. Stream won't be executed unless there exists a subscriber to it.
Have you had added one line to this code, you'll see `defer()` being executed:

```
    documentRepository.getDocuments(...)
                      .map { ...}
                      .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks! This also worked, but I decided to use @akanorkd's solution instead.